# Spring component scan across

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have an eclipse java project and under /src/main/java (package com.xxx.yyy). I also have a few Test classes under the /src/test/java  (under package com.xxx.yyy). The test class (which is annotated as @Service(value = "sampleclient") public class SampleClient { ... }
gets invoked by a framework code located in one of the packages under /src/main/java.

The component scan works fine if all the files/packages are under the /src/main/java. But it ignores the packages I have under /src/test/java.

How do I force spring to scan for components (packages) under multiple directories ?

Comment: Why are you calling test code from your production code?

Comment: To rephrase the question -  how can spring component scan configuration access packages under different directories/classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend  you to use either maven or gradle build system which has clear demarcation between source and test code and how it has to be used in build [life cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). That means you will be able to use any test classes while "test" phase and ignore after that. You can also manage test dependencies accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.prod.service, x.y.z.test.service" />
```

Comment: It works when x.y.z.prod.service and x.y.z.test.service are under the same directory /src/main/java but if you put x.y.z.test.service under /src/test/java the component scan is not picking it up, which is my original question... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try this.... have 2 separate spring configuration files. In one do a component scan of the test classes and in the other (i call this as main) import the other one. And in the main configuration do a component scan of the prod classes.